# SSD migration partitioning planning

Tags: osx, partition, ssd, cloning

## Objective

I have used Linux tools to modernize older systems with SSD drives:

- format & partition new SSD (gParted)
- migrate OS + apps (clonezilla, )

I am seeking to upgrade a [Macbook Air MacBookAir4,1 (11-inch, Mid 2011)](https://everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook-air/specs/macbook-air-core-i5-1.6-11-mid-2011-specs.html) (outfitted with El Capitan and Office 2011) [SSD documented here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360055/).

## Problem

When the SSD drive is upgraded, it has been my experience that Office 'sees' the change and will require a product key, which was never issued to the owner, despite the owner providing a receipt for purchasing the laptop and Office.  Microsoft acknowledges the purchase however it was unable to provide a product key.

## Strategy

Create a partition that is identical to the original drive to prevent Office from 'seeing' the change.

## Questions

1. Is the partition change the root cause of the Office issue and will the above strategy prevent office from demanding a product key?
2. What are the measurements (parameters) that define a partition so as to size and reconstruct the partition on the new drive?

Answer (score 1):

If your laptop is running OSX, just make a backup with time machine on an external disk, then change the laptop HDD with your SSD, boot the laptop using the recovery mode and reload your time machine backup.

Comment: Will time-machine prevent the Office 2011 product-key demand?

Comment: What would be the purpose of a backup system to ask you to re-enter your serial keys if you restore your machine ? :D

Comment: Unfortunately, Microsoft designed Office to monitor changes in the hard drive and demand a product activation key.  I think it was designed to ensure that users pay for using their software and follow their rules.  The intent is to upgrade to a larger drive: having a backup is a nice bonus

Comment: I'm pretty surprised about that in fact.